# Mounting a ntfs partition

Tags: mount, ntfs

I'm trying to load files from a windows 10 disk in ubuntu 20.04.

Here, how I mounting it:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb4 /mnt/DATA
```

But when i open it, i can see only some windows system files

[image: some windows system files]

Some help?
Thanks!

EDIT:

here is the output of `lsblk /dev/sdb`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   127M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0 899,7G  0 part /mnt/DATA
├─sdb5   8:21   0  1000M  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0    30G  0 part 
└─sdb7   8:23   0   500M  0 part
```

Comment: Sure, that this is the right partition and not the Windows recovery partition ? Please add the output of `lsblk /dev/sdb`

Comment: sure I've added it to the post

Comment: Thanks. Please make sure to add textual output as text :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem ;)

Comment: Edit your question by adding the result of `sudo lsblk` (only the part that concerns your hard disk not loop devices).